# Android Eclipse Hanging

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, freeze

I'm trying to get the ADT working in Eclipse, but I'm getting random hangs where eclipse just locks for no apparent reason, usually requiring a 'killall java' to properly clean it out of the memory.

I'm on Ubuntu 10.4 (64bit)
Here's the details of my eclipse/android install:

eclipse Version: 3.5.2
Build id: M20100211-1343
Android Development Tools 0.9.8.v201008281755-53891 com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group
Android DDMS 0.9.8.v201008281755-53891 com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.feature.group

Here's the output from java -version :
java version "1.6.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_20-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.3-b01, mixed mode)

I often don't get anything in the workspace logs, but here's an example of what appeared after Eclipse hung just now :
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 8 2 2010-09-21 10:22:27.407
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.core.resources".
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Project target not resolved yet.
 at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BaseBuilder.stopBuild(Unknown Source)
 at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BaseBuilder.abortOnBadSetup(Unknown Source)
 at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.PreCompilerBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:627)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:170)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:201)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:253)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:256)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:309)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:341)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:140)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:238)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
!SUBENTRY 1 com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 8 0 2010-09-21 10:22:27.407
!MESSAGE Project target not resolved yet.
!SUBENTRY 1 com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 8 0 2010-09-21 10:22:27.407
!MESSAGE Project target not resolved yet.

There were two of these entries - identical except for the timestamps.

I've tried just about every version of eclipse I can download, I've tried tying adt to sdk 1.6 r1, r2 and r3.

Anyone got any ideas?  I'm at my wits end here.  Eclipse is fairly solid for me using other plugins - C/C++, PyDev, PHP, Web stuff all work fine, but as soon as I try using the android plugin I start hanging. I've disabled code completion, in case it was that, but nope, whatever I seem to do, I get a couple of lines typed then everything goes grey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer one eclipse installation for each programming language/language pack. Java + Android, Php + Web (HTML, JS...), Python... Maybe ADT isn't really compatible to one of your installed plugins. Try to use a separate eclipse installation/instance

Comment: Actually that's where I've ended up due to this problem.  A separate eclipse with it's own workspace for each language/client.  It's a much better state of affairs than the mess I had before.  Didn't solve the android hang though :-(

Comment: Sorry for not closing this question sooner - work got in the way of play!  I ended up re-visiting this recently, on a new OS and the problem is no longer there.  Unfortunately I didn't manage to discover why I was crashing, so no help for anyone else suffering a similar problem... Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

I've had this happen due to a corrupt Eclipse workbench.  In particular, I've seen Eclipse hang while loading `com.android.ide.eclipse.adt` configuration.

First, I tried deleting `com.android.ide.eclipse.adt` from my workspace/.metadata/.plugins, but that did not do the trick.

However, deleting `org.eclipse.ui.workbench` from workspace/.metadata/.plugins seems to have done the trick.

Seems like the workbench configuration is getting corrupted somehow.  So, try this guys:

**`rm /path_to_workspaces/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench
-fr`**

Seems to have fixed the problem for me now, and I believe this was the same solution I came up with when I had the same problem 2 years ago ( but just now found this question on SO)

Answer (score 0):

Recently this problem keeps cropping up too.  I usually solve it by

```
1. Renaming org.eclipse.core.resources(in your *currently active workspace folder*/.metadata/plugins folder)  to something like org.eclipse.core.resources.old
2. Kill eclipse task if it is still hung in memory
3. Start eclipse, it should start fine and create org.eclipse.core.resources again
4. Close eclipse
5. Delete the newly created org.eclipse.core.resources folder and rename org.eclipse.core.resources.old to org.eclipse.core.resources
6. Start eclipse again.
```

This has worked for me