# Eclipse debugger for android virtual device hanging?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging, android-virtual-device

Saw [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759092/android-eclipse-hanging) but [nothing](http://www.infinitezest.com/articles/debugging-an-android-application.aspx) addresses what I see and have to work with:

```
[16:29:11 - com.XX.yy] Attempting to connect debugger to 'com.XX' on port 8852
```

No actual device just the Android emulator.

Runs correctly on the emulator (although takes a while to get running).

However, trying to debug and it just hangs.

Displays the message above and shows a black screen on the emulator...?

Any point in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Thank You .

Comment: have to tried to add this to manifest
either this
<manifest>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP"></uses-permission>
</manifest>

OR android:debuggable="true"  should work

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned line is waiting where you gave an break point in your program.

Always emulator is slow process while debug. To increase the eclipse speed by change the configuration file of eclipse in your eclipse folder and restart.

hope it help full

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting your current AVD and create a new one and then run the debugger again. Solved the problem in my case.